# Null Pointer Exception after inserting and reading from database

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have tried here writing to database and reading and loading them to an `ArrayList`,then the elements from the list are supposed to be added to an `AutoCompleteTextView`,but it seems to be showing `NullPointerException`.

Here's the code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tweetPost = new Tweet();
        setIssueTypeToDatabase("Accident");
        setIssueTypeToDatabase("Fire");
        setIssueTypeToDatabase("Local Utility Problem");
        setIssueTypeToDatabase("Theft");
        setIssueTypeToDatabase("Technological Problem");


    postBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.post);
    log.debug(postBox);
    issue = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_issue);
    log.debug(issue);
    setIssueTypeFromDatabaseToList();
    adapterA = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, IssueTypeList);

    issue.setAdapter(adapterA);
    }


private void setIssueTypeToDatabase(String issue) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = issueTypeDatabase.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(IssueTypeDatabase.C_Issue, issue);
    db.insertOrThrow(IssueTypeDatabase.TABLE, null, values);

}

private void setIssueTypeFromDatabaseToList() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = issueTypeDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(IssueTypeDatabase.TABLE, FROM, null, null, null, null,
            ORDER_BY);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    showEvents(cursor);
}

private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
    log.debug("showEvents()");
    // Stuff them all into a big string
    setContentView(R.layout.database);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // Could use getColumnIndexOrThrow() to get indexes
        issueTypesFound = cursor.getString(1);

        IssueTypeList.add(issueTypesFound);


    }
    cursor.close();
}


    public class IssueTypeDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    // Static Final Variable database meta information

    static final String DATABASE = "IssueType.db";
    static final int VERSION =4;
    public static final String TABLE = "IssueTypeTable";
    static final String TABLE_DEPT = "Issue_Dept";

    public static final String C_ID = "_id";
    public static final String C_Issue = "issue";

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IssueTypeDatabase.class);
    // Override constructor
    public IssueTypeDatabase(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
        log.debug("IssueTypeDatabse()");

    }

    // Override onCreate method
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        log.debug("onCreate()");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ( " + C_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + C_Issue + " TEXT"+");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        log.debug("onUpgrade()>>SQLiteDatabase={}",DATABASE);
        // Drop old version table
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

        // Create New Version table
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And the Log:

[image: Log]

Comment: I see here also that you have a startManagingCursor and a cursor.close() on the same cursor, those should not be used together i don't think.

Comment: Thanx,I removed the cursor.close() and modified it a little,it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what was the error,cursor.close() was causing the problem,again I made another stupid mistake,I set a layout in my showEvents() method,which was causing the screen to change rapidly.
so removing cursor.close() and setContentView(R.layout.database) did the trick.